# ZeroMQ Curve Assertion with ZAP handler on Client side

Tags: zeromq

This problem may be a bit obscure... I'm encountering a ZeroMQ assertion on connections when I configure a client process (the side that connects, not binds) as a curve server with a custom ZAP handler. This configuration is backwards from the examples I've looked at - in that usually the curve server is the side the binds, and the client connects); however, the documentation indicates that it doesn't matter which side binds or connects.

In the ZAP handler, if the curve client credentials are valid, the connection is established and everything works. However, if the credentials are invalid and the ZAP handler responds with a "400" status code, ZeroMQ asserts right afterwards. The exact assert is "**`Assertion failed: zap_pipe == NULL (src/session_base.cpp:301)`**". I have verified that if I reverse which side binds and connects, there is no assertion.

> ZMQ version is 4.1.4,
>  running on Ubuntu 16.04.9,
> gcc 5.4.0.  <sub>( [@Dale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50052300/zeromq-curve-assertion-with-zap-handler-on-client-side?noredirect=1#comment87145709_50052300) )</sub>

I've not been able to find detailed documentation specifying how the ZAP handler is supposed to work - so perhaps there is another code that should be returned?

Has anyone else ever tried this?

Comment: Brgds to ORNL. Would you mind to post a **C**omplete **M**C**VE**-code, as mandatory for StackOverflow? ( May also re-read the Policy on this. ) Any narrative is by far **not** a Complete and can **not** reproduce the claim, **the less V**erify any solution approach. You may review and update your post. Best also include a call to **`zmq_version (&major, &minor, &patch);`** and **`printf ("Current ØMQ version is %d.%d.%d\n", major, minor, patch);`**. That's fair and matching the StackOverflow standard policies, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry for the rambling narrative - my question is really about finding low-level documentation and/or insights for authoring ZAP handlers. I'm new to ZAP and curve, so it's highly likely that my code is not compliant with the protocol. (Thus my reluctance to post an MCVE.) ZMQ version is 4.1.4, running on Ubuntu 16.04.9, gcc 5.4.0.

Comment: I missed the fact that the ZAP protocol spec (https://rfc.zeromq.org/spec:27/ZAP/) does in fact list all status codes as well as all other fields in the handler reply. So, this appears to be a bug in ZeroMQ and I will open a ticket in their tracking system.